# Compilation error when using co_await

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

Why when I build own custom class, I get the following errors?

Header:

```
namespace PSImageLibrary {
    public ref class PSImage sealed {

    public:
        PSImage();
        virtual ~PSImage();

        IAsyncAction^open(StorageFile^ file);

    private:
        IRandomAccessStream^ stream;
        BitmapDecoder^ decoder;
        PixelDataProvider^ provider;
        BitmapTransform^ transform;

        IAsyncAction^_decode(IRandomAccessStream^);
    };
}
```

Implementation:

```
PSImageLibrary::PSImage::PSImage() {
    transform = ref new BitmapTransform();
}

PSImageLibrary::PSImage::~PSImage() { }

IAsyncAction^ PSImageLibrary::PSImage::open(StorageFile^ file) {
    return create_async([this, file] {
        return create_async([this, file]() -> task<void> {
            stream = co_await file->OpenAsync(FileAccessMode::Read);
            co_await _decode(stream);
        });
    });
}

IAsyncAction^ PSImageLibrary::PSImage::_decode(IRandomAccessStream^ stream) {
    return create_async([this, stream] {
        return create_async([this, stream]() -> task<void> {
            decoder = co_await BitmapDecoder::CreateAsync(stream);
        });
    });
}
```

My exception occurs here:

```
__declspec(non_user_code) __declspec(no_refcount) __declspec(no_release_return)
    inline void* __abi_winrt_ptr_assign(void** __ppTargetArg, const volatile ::Platform::Object^ __objArg)
{
    __abi_IUnknown* __pUnknown = reinterpret_cast<__abi_IUnknown*>(const_cast< ::Platform::Object^>(__objArg));
    __abi_IUnknown** __ppTargetUnknown = reinterpret_cast<__abi_IUnknown**>(__ppTargetArg);
    if (__pUnknown != *__ppTargetUnknown)
    {
        if (__pUnknown) {
            __pUnknown->__abi_AddRef();
        }
        if (*__ppTargetUnknown) {
            (*__ppTargetUnknown)->__abi_Release();
        }
        *__ppTargetUnknown = __pUnknown;
    }
    return __pUnknown;
}
```

I think that error appears when I appropriate file->OpenAsync to stream, but I don't know why error appears. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a Windows Runtime Component you're compiling? They cannot contain task's as public return values - you'll want to return `IAsyncAction^`'s instead.

You can use `create_async` to do this, and some examples are here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/winrt-components/walkthrough-creating-a-basic-windows-runtime-component-in-cpp-and-calling-it-from-javascript-or-csharp

In your case, perhaps something like the following:

```
IAsyncAction^ PSImageLibrary::PSImage::open(StorageFile^ file) {
    return create_async([file]
    {
        stream = co_await file->OpenAsync(FileAccessMode::Read);    
        _decode();
    });
}
```